# Don't understand why one is working and not the other one

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can someone explain me why does the first function get trough and not the second one. I can't figure out why I cannot assign a new var to the parameter 'string_' I tried to search online but I can't find a name to that problem therefore I am running in circles.

#### First

```
def disemvowel(string_):
    for i in "aeiouAEIOU":
        string_ = string_.replace(i, "")
    return string_
```

#### Second

```
def disemvowel(string_):
    for i in "aeiouAEIOU":
        string = string_.replace(i, "")
    return string
```

Comment: You keep overwriting `string` in the second function at every iteration.

Comment: Aside from your question, note that this approach is very inefficient. You need to read/replace again the whole string for each vowel. Prefer an approach with a regex or reading the string character by character and comparing to a set of the vowels.

Comment: I pass in string `"aeiou"`. *Iteration 1:* `string = "eiou"` `string_="aeiou"`. *Iteration 2:* `string = "aiou"` `string_="aeiou"`. *Iteration 3:* `string = "aeou"` `string_="aeiou"`.  That's why this doesn't work.

Comment: You can check what's going inside and compare these two methods with help of https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes a small `print` is better that an long explanation:

Option 1 (**cumulative** modifications):

```
def disemvowel(string_):
    for i in "aeiouAEIOU":
        string_ = string_.replace(i, "")
        print(i, string_)

disemvowel('aeizAEIZ')

a eizAEIZ
e izAEIZ
i zAEIZ
o zAEIZ
u zAEIZ
A zEIZ
E zIZ
I zZ
O zZ
U zZ
```

Option 2 (**successive** modifications):

```
def disemvowel(string_):
    for i in "aeiouAEIOU":
        string = string_.replace(i, "")
        print(i, string)

disemvowel('aeizAEIZ')

a eizAEIZ
e aizAEIZ
i aezAEIZ
o aeizAEIZ
u aeizAEIZ
A aeizEIZ
E aeizAIZ
I aeizAEZ
O aeizAEIZ
U aeizAEIZ
```

Answer (score 0):

The second function uses the unmodified caller argument for each `replace`, assigning to a different variable. As such, only the final `replace` (for `'U'`) has any effect. Reusing the argument (as you did in the first function) means you accumulate the changes rather than discarding each one in favor of the latest.

As a side-note, the work you're doing could be done in a single operation instead of requiring 10 separate `replace` calls:

```
# Done outside the function once so it can be reused without the expense of
# rebuilding it
# Creates a dict mapping all vowels to None, for use with str.translate,
# which interprets mapping to None as "delete this character"
_kill_vowels_table = str.maketrans('', '', 'aeiouAEIOU')
def disemvowel(string):
    return string.translate(_kill_vowels_table)
```

Comment: Side-note: `str.maketrans` created tables are more general (work with all Unicode characters, not just ASCII/latin-1), but in this particular case, since you only need to delete ASCII vowels, you could make a more efficient, if uglier to read, table with: `_kill_vowels_table = tuple(None if code in b'aeiouAEIOU' else code for code in range(256))` `str.maketrans` doesn't actually need a `dict`, just something that accepts `int`s for lookup and raises `LookupError` (parent of `KeyError` and `IndexError`) on failure, and `tuple`s are cheaper to index than `dict` lookup. Only use if perf critical.

Answer (score 0):

It seems not working in the second code piece because you assigned the result of `replace` method to a different variable each time. If you type any input that finishes with `U` character you will see that it will be replaced with empty string.

```
def disemvowel(muz):
    for i in "aeiouAEIOU":
        elma = muz.replace(i, "")
    return elma
    
    
print (disemvowel('ovyeahbananaU'))
```

it returns `ovyeahbanana`

Answer (score 0):

In 2nd code. As `string_` is unmodified on next for-loop run it won't remove the elements it removed before. So it will continue until last chr ("U" in your case). So it will only replace last chr with `""`.

```py
def disemvowel_notworking(string_):
    for i in "aeiouAEIOU":
        string = string_.replace(i, "")
    return string

print(disemvowel_notworking("HELLO WORLD Ucheck"))
```

output

```
HELLO WORLD check
```